# Haskell trying to understand typeclass syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax, typeclass

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to understand the syntax. I have data type `Vec` and it implements `Show`, `Floating` and `Foldable`. But the syntax is different for `Foldable`, why?

```
data Vec a = Vec [a]

instance Show a => Show (Vec a) where
   show (Vec x) = show x

instance Floating a => Floating (Vec a) where
  pi = Vec (repeat pi)
  exp (Vec x) = Vec (map exp x)
  log (Vec x) = Vec (map log x)
  sin (Vec x) = Vec (map sin x)
  cos (Vec x) = Vec (map cos x)

instance Foldable Vec where
  foldr f x (Vec y) = foldr f x y
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your instance for `Foldable` is "self-contained", it does not depend on the availability of other instances (of this or a different type class).

But for your instance of `Show (Vec a)` you also need an instance of `Show a` first (so that you can in your implementation call `show x`).

That `=>` syntax establishes this requirement/dependency.

Comment: What about `foldr f x y`? am I not using `foldr`?

Comment: You are calling `foldr x y` for `y :: [a]`. There is an instance for that (in `List`), completely unconstrained in the type of `y`. You can call List functions like `y : Nil` for any `y`. But you cannot call `show y` or `cos y` without having a typeclass for it.

Comment: The OP's question isn't very well explained - but aside from the presence or lack of constraints on the instance, another difference is that `Show` and `Floating` apply to "concrete types" (with kind `*`) like `Vec a`, whereas `Foldable` applies to "type constructors" (of kind `* -> *`) like `Vec` itself. This might also have been a source of confusion for the OP and is worthy of comment